# A question about $\text{limsup}_{n \to \infty}(a_n)$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $a_n$ is a sequence of **non-negative** real numbers and suppose that $\text{limsup}_{n \to \infty}(a_n)=0$.

(a) Can we deduce that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exist and equal $0$?

(b) If $\text{limsup}_{n \to \infty} b_n=1$, can we deduce that $\text{limsup}_{n \to \infty} a_nb_n=0$ ?

**My attempt**: (a) If $\text{limsup}_{n \to \infty}(a_n)=0$, then for any subsequence $a_{n_k}$ we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n_k}=0$. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exist and equal $0$.

(b) If (a) is true, then I know that (b) is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) \geq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) \geq \inf_{n \in N} a_n \geq 0$ This implies that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)=0$.

You stated in your question that you can prove (b) without further help. I hope this is a succint proof for (a).

Comment: Thanks Jake, but $0\leq\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)$ is not trivial ? How can we deduced that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)$ ?

Comment: @boaz It is given that the $\lim \sup$ is $0$.

Comment: Right! sorry. Thanks

Comment: @boaz if you are referring to the $\inf$ of a set of non-negative numbers is greater than equal to zero. $Liminf$ is $\geq$ to $inf$

Answer (score 1):

(a) is true, but your reasoning is not quite clear. How are you claiming that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} = 0$ for every subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$? You need to justify why that limit exists.

In this case, we can note that we have $$\lim\sup a_n = 0 \le \liminf a_n$$
and thus, $\limsup a_n = \liminf a_n = 0$. With this, we get that $\lim a_n$ exists and equals $0$.